# Is RTMP suitable for my web application?

Tags: webrtc, rtmp, live-streaming

I am building a web application that will have a few dozen people at a time live streaming. Each stream will have around 8 viewers. The "viewers" will be able to chat with the "streamers" in a chat bar. So I need low latency.

I am thinking of implementing this by having the "streamers" use [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) to push a stream to [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/) (media server) and then serve up the content via RTMP and playback in the browser with an RTMP player.

I am very new to the world of streaming, my background is just in LAMP stack development of websites.

**I have two questions.**

1. Am I headed in the right direction for creating this application?
2. With flash being slowly killed, should I even build it using RTMP? Or is WebRTC a better option?

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC is the better option. Flash is being discontinued by Adobe, so if there is a chance your application will stick around for a few years, pick WebRTC. It's feature set is also better for things like acoustic echo suppression, dynamic bitrate adjustment, and security.

No, RTMP is not a good choice for this application. RTMP is a TCP-based protocol, which means that any dropped packets will cause high latency while waiting for retransmission.

If you stick with Flash-based technologies, RTMFP would be a better choice because it is a UDP-based protocol.

Comment: If your streamers would use web browsers to encode and stream, then yes, WebRTC would be a good choice. But since Cody is going to use standalone OBS encoders, WebRTC is out of context here. It's either WebRTC without OBS (first choice), or OBS->Wowza->RTMP, or OBS->Unreal Media Server->HTML5 low latency player.

Comment: @user1390208 My reading of the question is that OBS is part of the proposed solution and not a requirement.

Comment: I’m not against them encoding within the browser. I just want a technology that will work for the next couple of years, with low latency and decent quality. This app needs a one to many stream. The “viewers” should not have streaming capabilities. I have noticed a lot of very popular streaming sites like this are still using flash.

Comment: OK, then go with WebRTC. It's going to provide you the minimal possible latency, and it's going to be around for next two years for sure. And your streamers don't need to install standalone encoding/streaming software.

Comment: The fact that this doesn't run in a browser shouldn't deter people from using WebRTC - it would still be the best open source alternative around (and a high quality one at that)

Comment: Tsahi - What standalone encoder will encode VP8 video and Opus Audio? OBS will surely not do it. That's the main reason (not the only one) I am saying you should go with WebRTC only if your encoding is also done by WebRTC. At least today.

Comment: I decided ultimately not to go with a WebRTC only solution. I am using Wowza media server to serve up the content in different protocols. Thank you to everyone who gave me input.